# Is there a way to detect sitemap, if it is not in robots.txt?

Tags: sitemap, robots.txt

I'm working for a simple bot for a project, and I noticed, that a lot of sites do not have sitemaps in their robot.txt files. There is of course an option to simply index the sites in question and crawl all possible pages, but that often takes much more time than simply downloading sitemap.

What is the best way to detect sitemap if it is not mentioned in robots.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally it should be placed in the root directory of a domain like xydomain.xyz/sitemap.xml .

I would only add the site map into the robots file, if it is placed elsewhere. If a site uses more than one site map located on another place, it should be noted in an [index map](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=71453).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [online tool](https://www.xml-sitemaps.com) to scan your site and create a bespoke sitemap.xlm file for your site.

To help your sitemap to be discovered through the robot.txt add the URL of your sitemap at the very top of your robot.txt file, (see below example).

So, the robots.txt file looks like this:

```css
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
User-agent:*
Disallow:
```